# Perl :: Translate String "yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss" into DateTime object?

Tags: string, datetime, perl, type-conversion

newbie Perl guy here.  I have a Perl script (v5.26.1) that parses a logfile.  For reasons beyond my control, the format of each date in the log is this:

```
"yyyy.mm.dd.hh.mm.ss"
```

e.g.:

```
"2022.09.19.16.35.00"
```

Note that year is always four digits, while month, day, hour, minute, and second are always two digits.  (e.g. Sept is `09`)

I need to convert this string into a DateTime object for comparison purposes.  I thought this exercise would be a breeze, but five hours and a lot of fruitless Google searches later, and I'm no-where close.  Here's my first attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub transStrToDTime
{
    # Example format of a date:  "2022.09.19.16.35.00"
    my $str = @_;           # Only one input argument

    use DateTime qw( );
    my ($y,$m,$d,$h,$m,$s) = $str =~ /^([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})\z/
        or die;
    my $dt = DateTime->new(
       year      => $y,
       month     => $m,
       day       => $d,
       hour      => $h,
       minute    => $m,
       second    => $s,
       time_zone => 'local'
    );
    printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=->>> \"$dt\"\n");
}

my $str="2022.09.19.16.35.00";
transStrToDTime($str);
```

Code has a syntax error:

```
me@ubuntu:/home/me# ./toyPerl.pl
Died at ./toyPerl.pl line 16.
me@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

Where line 16 is:

```
    my ($y,$m,$d,$h,$m,$s) = $str =~ /^([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})\z/
```

Ugggggggghhhhhhhhh...  After reading up on this topic and becoming more confused, I decided to do the conversion manually.  I figured that all I had to do is:

- `split()` the string on `.`
- Build a new DateTime object with the string tokens as input:

Here's that attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str="2022.09.19.16.35.00";
my @spl = split('.', $line);
#Lets look at the tokens before we build the DateTime object:
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#spl; $i++){
    print("$i)  $spl[$i] \n");
}
```

Output:

```
me@ubuntu:/home/me# ./toyPerl.pl
me@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

No output... meaning that `split()` split `"2022.09.19.16.35.00"` ***into zero tokens?***  Is `$str` not a string, then?  So what data type could it be?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str="2022.09.19.16.35.00";
printf("Verifying that \$str is a string:\n");
printf("---> ${ref($str)}\n");
```

Output:

```
me@ubuntu:/home/me# ./toyPerl.pl
Verifying that "2022.09.19.16.35.00" is a string:
Can't use string ("") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at ./2222toyPerl.pl line 7.
me@ubuntu:/home/me#
```

Where line 7 is this line:

```
printf("---> ${ref($str)}\n");
```

I'm so confused.  The error message seems to say that my string isn't a scalar.  But I thought strings were scalar in Perl?  ("[A scalar is most often either a number or a string.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_scalars.htm)")  And why is the string reduced to an empty string (`""`) in line 7?

Oh man.  This post represents half a day's work.  Can anyone spot my syntax error in the first method?  And why can't I `split()` string `"2022.09.19.16.35.00"`?  Is it not a string or something?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you put

```
my $str = @_;
```

It means you put the array in scalar context, and in scalar context, arrays return their size. What you want is to use list context:

```
my ($str) = @_;
```

Or better yet, use the idiomatic `shift`:

```
my $str = shift;   # automatically uses @_ inside a subroutine
```

You are also using two `$m` variables. Change one of them to something else. Revised code works as expected:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub transStrToDTime {
    my ($str) = @_;           # Only one input argument
    use DateTime qw( );
    my ($y,$M,$d,$h,$m,$s) = $str =~ /^([0-9]{4}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2}).([0-9]{2})\z/
        or die;
    my $dt = DateTime->new(
       year      => $y,
       month     => $M,
       day       => $d,
       hour      => $h,
       minute    => $m,
       second    => $s,
       time_zone => 'local'
    );
    printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=->>> \"$dt\"\n");
}

my $str="2022.09.19.16.35.00";
transStrToDTime($str);
```

Output:

```
=-=-=-=-=-=-=->>> "2022-09-19T16:35:00"
```

The thing you call a syntax error in the first method is actually not a syntax error. Just your code that says `die` if the regex match fails. Note that `die` without a message is not terribly informative. You might want to put something more useful there.

In your second case, when you split on `'.'`, you are using a wildcard character `.`, not a literal period. Hence the entire string is consumed and nothing is left. You might try `split /\./` instead.

In the third case, I don't know what you are doing here: `${ref($str)}` You are trying to dereference the return value from `ref`? The return value from `ref` is just a string, e.g. `ARRAY` or `SCALAR`. That's not how you use `ref`. If you want to know what a variable contains, instead use `Data::Dumper`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $str;
# will print $VAR1 = 1; in your first program ($str is the size of the array @_)
```

Also, this line:

```
    printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=->>> \"$dt\"\n");
```

1. Don't use `printf` when you can use `print`. `printf` has a special usage.
2. Instead of escaping quotes inside the string, consider alternatives such as:

```perl
printf " '%s' \n", $dt;   # using printf correctly
print " '$dt' \n";        # more simple
print qq( "$dt" \n);      # different delimiter
use feature 'say';
say " '$dt' ";            # say includes newline at the end
```

Comment: Re "*Don't use `printf` when you can use `print`.*", Or rather, use `printf` correctly if you're going to use `printf`: `printf("=-=-=-=-=-=-=->>> \"%s\"\n", $dt);` But yeah, `print` is easier here, and `say` easier yet.

Comment: @ikegami Included that in my suggestions now.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to everything TLP said, you can use

```perl
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
   pattern   => '%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S',
   strict    => 1,
   time_zone => 'local',
   on_error  => 'croak',
));

my $dt = $format->parse_datetime( $str );
```

Comment: This is clearly the correct solution, my answer is more about what was wrong with the original code.